# How Can I know the exact paragraph where delete key was down?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, backbone.js

Let's say we have a html like below.

```
<div class="my_content" contenteditable="true">
    <div class="my_paragraph"><span style="color:red;">RED</span><span style="color:green;">GREEN</span></div>
    <div class="my_paragraph"><span style="font-size:1em">1EM-TEXT</span><div>
    <div class="my_paragraph"><span style="font-size:2em">2EM-TEXT</span><div>
</div>
```

And I have a Backbone viewer like below.

```
 events: {
    "keydown .my_paragraph" :"onKeyDown"
 },

 onKeyDown : function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode === 46) { //delete key
     }
 }
```

Q. In the 'if' at the onKeyDown Method, How can I get the exact-paragraph which is user try to delete (by press delete key)?

Comment: it will depend also where you put the delete button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
onKeyDown : function(e) {
     if(e.keyCode === 46) { //delete key
     }
 }
```

You expect an event to be passed in your example that is the param `e`
You can identify what paragraph is focus using `e.target`  object

**Update:**

---

As what have derek said, divs cannot listen to keypress event unless you set content editable to true.

For this to work , remove the contenteditable of parent div and set this property in each of the child

```js
$(function(){
  $('.my_paragraph').on('keydown', function(e){
       console.log(e.target);
  });
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="my_content">
    <div class="my_paragraph first" contenteditable="true"><span style="color:red;">RED</span>"><span style="color:green;">GREEN</span></div>
    <div class="my_paragraph second" contenteditable="true"><span style="font-size:1em">1EM-TEXT</span></div>
    <div class="my_paragraph third" contenteditable="true"><span style="font-size:2em">2EM-TEXT</span></div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will still return the `.my_content` that contains `contenteditable="true"`

Comment: @DerekStory it depends in the focus field

Comment: It doesn't. There is no focus field for a `div` that doesn't contain `contenteditable="true"`. Using the current example (use spacebar) - http://codepen.io/anon/pen/kXAowA?editors=1010#0

Answer (score 1):

You could do something along the lines of:

```
var cursorTarget = getSelection().getRangeAt(0).commonAncestorContainer.parentNode;
var targetParagraph = $('.my_paragraph').has(cursorTarget);
targetParagraph.addClass('target-paragraph'); // Or whatever you want
```

[Codepen Example](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/RRZkBK?editors=1010#0) (Use spacebar for example)

---

**Also important:** You have invalid html. You aren't properly using closing `</div>` tags in the last two `.my_paragraph` divs and there is an extra `">` after closing the first `span`.

Comment: This works! Thanks a lot to answer my Question. However, I am trying not to use getSelection because it's not a standard yet and too much different ways to get it depends on the browser. I am hoping that I can get another way if It's possible

Comment: You will probably need something a lot more robust to get the cursor position. That or apply the `contenteditable="true"`  to the individual `.my_paragraph` divs instead, but i have a feeling that isn't desired.

Comment: @DerekStory same thoughts :) just remove the contenteditable of parent and apply to each child